# Web API Request is null when calling from other API controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have 2 Web API controllers:
1. Runtime1Controller
2. Runtime2Controller

In Runtime2Controller:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateRequest(KeyRequest keyRequest)
    {
        try
        {
            Runtime1Controller runtime1Controller = new Runtime1Controller();
            HttpResponseMessage response = runtime1Controller.PostCreateRequest(keyRequest);

            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

            return response;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In Runtime1Controller, I return HttpResponse message:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateRequest(KeyRequest keyRequest)
{
    // Process Data .....
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, keyRequest);
}
```

Then, why All the time Request is NULL. If I directly call Runtime1Controller PostCreateRequest, it is not NULL. Why SO???

Answer (score 0):

in Runtime1Controller, use return when you create the response (or maybe you dont put this part):

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostCreateRequest(KeyRequest keyRequest)
{
    // Process Data .....
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, keyRequest);
}
```

Comment: Correct, I forgot to add return, but the problem is "Request" in Request.CreateResponse is NULL.